# chosen jquery plugin: how to open dropdown thru javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I'm using [Chosen jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). I am trying to open a dropdown thru javascript. To be specific, I want a dropdown to open after a choice has been selected from a previous dropdown.

I've tried this (select1 being the previous dropdown and select2 being the next) :

```
$("select").chosen();

$("#select1").next().bind("click", function () {

      $('#select2').trigger('chosen:open');

});
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

HTML :

```
<select id="select1">
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
</select>
<select id="select3">
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript :

```
$('select').chosen()

$('select').on('chosen:hiding_dropdown' , function(){
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(that).nextAll('select').first().trigger('chosen:open');
  } , 200);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yann86/5c2tfwze/

Comment: This works if there are no containers for the select. What if they are  in containers? eg. <div><select1></select></div><div><select2></select></div>

Comment: You need to adapt the jquery selector to the new DOM  situation